# Django website running on Azure web app extremely slow

Tags: django, azure

I have a django web app which I have deployed to an Azure web app (running on the B1 app service plan). The website works as intended, except for the loading time which can routinely take up to 10 minutes to load a single page (even with cached static files).

While I have not correctly set up a web hosting platform and are instead simply running the server using the default manage.py system, the website still should not be running this slowly. Is there a simple way to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Comment: How did you overcome this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you running with manage.py, it may possible that you face performance issue or django web server thread issue. For performance you must configure django application with Apache2or IIS server.

Django web server is for debugging purpose only.

Recommend you to use Azure web services fir website.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code runs normally on the local side, I suggest you try to change from `FastCGI` to `httpPlatformHandler` in your `web.config` file.You could follow this 
[tutorial](https://prmadi.com/django-app-with-httpplatformhandler-in-azure-app-services-windows/).

In addition, please refer to this [official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation) doc to troubleshooting the performance of your Azure web app.

Answer (score -4):

Optimize your code, where is blocking. I am also running website on Azure but never face slowly response even in free instance.

Comment: My code is fine if it was the code itself running slowly then it would run slowly on a local instance as well as on the server.